# MySqlException in Nhibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

I have written a test mysql connection project in Nhibernate. this exception is showing..

```
    NHibernate.HibernateException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax;
    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
    syntax to use near 'Character (Id VARCHAR(40) not null, Name
    VARCHAR(255), HealthPoints INTEGER, Man' at line 1'
```

The `hibernate.cfg.xml` file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
    <session-factory name="NHibernate.Test">
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">
            Database=nhibernate;Data Source=localhost;User Id=ajoy;Password=ajoy
        </property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The model class is

```
namespace NhibernateTest.Domain
{
    public class Character
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual int HealthPoints { get; set; }
        public virtual int Mana { get; set; }
        public virtual string Profession { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The mapping xml is ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NhibernateTest"
                   namespace="NhibernateTest.Domain">

  <class name="Character">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <property name="HealthPoints" />
    <property name="Mana" />
    <property name="Profession" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

My main class is

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoadNHibernateCfg();

            /* CRUD */
            CharacterRepository repo = new CharacterRepository();

            //CREATE!
            var MikeAbyss = new Character { Name = "MikeAbyss", HealthPoints = 700, Mana = 10, Profession = "Knight" };
            repo.Add(MikeAbyss);

            //READ!
            Character mike = repo.GetCharacterByName("MikeAbyss");

            //UPDATE!
            mike.Name = "Mike";
            repo.Update(mike);

            //DELETE!
            repo.Delete(mike);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void LoadNHibernateCfg()
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.Configure();
            cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Character).Assembly);
            SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(cfg);
            schemaExport.SetDelimiter(";");
            schemaExport.Execute(true, true, false);

        }
```

I have tried without `schemaExport.SetDelimiter(";");` but still the same error.
Output in the console is

```
drop table if exists Character;

    create table Character (
        Id VARCHAR(40) not null,
       Name VARCHAR(255),
       HealthPoints INTEGER,
       Mana INTEGER,
       Profession VARCHAR(255),
       primary key (Id)
    );
```

Mysql version is 5.7.14. How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One or more of your identifiers are probably [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). You need to [quote them](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers): define their db names surrounded with back-ticks.

By example, quoting `Character` and `Name`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NhibernateTest"
                   namespace="NhibernateTest.Domain">      
  <class name="Character" table="`Character`">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="`Name`" />
    <property name="HealthPoints" />
    <property name="Mana" />
    <property name="Profession" />
  </class>        
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: This error is showing after using this xml `NHibernate.MappingException: 'Could not compile the mapping document: NhibernateTest.Mapping.Character.hbm.xml'`

Comment: It would be `<class name="Character" table="\`Character\`" >` . It also works if I refactor the the class name to any non reserved words. It worked without changing `name` field. Please correct your answer so that I can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Yes my bad, fixed. `Name` is keyword but not reserved, I was including it as an example.